# How to label the points in `ListPointPlot3D`

Tags: plotting, labeling

To label 2D point plot is easy, eg

```
ListPlot[Labeled[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{1, 1} -> 1, {6, 5} -> 
    2, {4, 1} -> 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

gives

[image]

But for `ListPointPlot3D`, this didn't work

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Labeled[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{1, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 2} -> 
    2, {1, 1, 3} -> 3}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

gives errors. So how to label the points in `ListPointPlot3D` as in 2D cases?

Comment: You can use a `Text[]` primitive instead.

Comment: @J.M. Do you mean change `Labeled[#[[1]], #[[2]]]` to `Text[#[[1]], #[[2]]]`? But not working

Comment: No, put them in a separate `Graphics3D[]` and combine with `Show[]`.